# Raspberry PI and U-Boot

Tags: raspberry-pi, u-boot, buildroot

I wish you a good day
I'm trying U-Boot on RPi and in short - I'm stuck that when I put any dtoverlay in config.txt, after turning on RPi it's just hangs on rainbow RPi splash screen
I have created rootfs using buildroot 2020.02.1 and U-Boot 2020.01

[buildroot config for U-Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJetM.png)

When I have just this in config.txt:

```
[pi0w]
kernel=uboot_rpi_0_w.bin

[all]
device_tree_address=0x03000000

hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=watchdog=on
```

and boot.scr I create using this:

```
setenv fdt_addr_r 0x03000000
setenv kernel_addr_r 0x01000000

fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r}
fdt get value bootargs /chosen bootargs

load mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} zImage
bootz ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}
```

so RPi boots fine. But once I add to config.txt for example "dtoverlay = miniuart-bt" then nothing - only rainbow. I need to add this 3 dtbo: "miniuart-bt, vc4-fkms-v3d, ads7846"

My original config.txt (without U-Boot):

```
boot_delay=1
kernel=zImage

hdmi_drive=1
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

avoid_warnings=1
disable_overscan=1
disable_splash=1
force_turbo=1

gpu_mem_256=128
gpu_mem_512=128
gpu_mem_1024=128

dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=watchdog=on

dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

# Display configuration [WaveShare 4inch HDMI LCD]
dtoverlay=ads7846
dtparam=penirq=25
dtparam=xomhs=60
dtparam=xmin=300
dtparam=xmax=3750
dtparam=ymin=150
dtparam=ymax=3800
dtparam=rotate=0
dtparam=swapxy=0

hdmi_force_mode=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=480 800 60 6 0 0 0
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to comment the `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` line when you're using `dtoverlay=ads7846` at the same time.